# remove values above a certain range from color scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do i set the color bar that it does not include values for a given range. For example in the code below

```
library(ggplot2)
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color=hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(4),
  limits=c(50, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(10,20),
                     breaks =seq(from=10,to=20,by=2))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(70,300),
                     breaks = seq(from = 70, to = 300, by = 20))

p2
```

With this I get 7 points which all fall outside the range of color scale (50-100). How can I exclude points that fall outside the values for color scale? In this example I should be getting no points in my final plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via the `na.value` argument in `scale_color_gradientn`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color=hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(4),
                        limits=c(50, 100), na.value = "transparent") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(10,20),
                     breaks =seq(from=10,to=20,by=2))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(70,300),
                     breaks = seq(from = 70, to = 300, by = 20))

p2
#> Warning: Removed 25 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>